# ElasticBeanstalk environment SWAP URL not Working

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-rds, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have existing Elastic Beanstalk environment(EC2+RDS) in non VPC. So in order to make use of VPC, I took snapshot of RDS and created new elastic beanstalk using VPC. Now when I do SWAP URL environment, I am unable to access the new environment with old URL. Is it because it will take some time for DNS records update  or I am missing something ? (Domain is not managed by AWS)

Any leads will be helpfull.

Thanks

Comment: I have solved my self. Unfortunately HTTPS port is not opened in security group.